# Made a generic fonction returning type of a key of an enum

Tags: typescript, generics, types, enums, discord.js

I have this enum (in a constant object because TS enums can't have types for values):

```js
export const DataType = {
    command: Command,
    channel: GuildChannel,
    emoji: Emoji,
    guild: Guild,
    user: User,
    member: GuildMember,
    role: Role,
    message: Message,
}
// all values are classes that I import from a module
```

Then I have this function that should return the type from the key set in your argument:

```js
export async function getThing<T extends keyof typeof DataType>(dataType: T , text: string): Promise<typeof DataType[T] | null | undefined> {
 /* some really long code, simply a switch that will have different behavior from the type set
    and return an instance of the type required */
}
```

This function should return `Command | null | undefined` when I do `getThing('command', aMessage)`.
It should return `Guild | null | undefined` when I do `getThing(DataType.guild, aMessage)`.

But I don't know how to get it functional, I get a lot of errors when returning a Command or a Guild or something else :/

Comment: I believe all you need to do is use `as const` for your DataType object (see https://tsplay.dev/rNd60W). This will prevent types narrowing and seems to work - otherwise can you provide a typescript playground link to show your error?

Comment: [tsplay.dev/KN74Bm](https://tsplay.dev/KN74Bm) there.
Also I applied your tip but it doesn't fix it.

Comment: @mbdavis so did you found a solution?